# installing mongodb into my computer

Tags: ros, installation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, friends

I have simple question about how to install mongodb into my computer.
I am working on laser_slam and I installed svn. When I run the code below,

$ roslaunch laser_slam laser_slam.launch

ERROR: cannot launch node of type [mongodb/wrapper.py]: Cannot locate installation of package mongodb: [rospack] couldn't find package [mongodb]. ROS_ROOT[/opt/ros/electric/ros] ROS_PACKAGE_PATH[/home/jkim/ros_workspace:/opt/ros/electric/stacks:/opt/ros/electric/stacks]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [laser_slam/laser_slam_node]: Cannot locate node of type [laser_slam_node] in package [laser_slam]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [laser_slam/cloud_snapshotter]: Cannot locate node of type [cloud_snapshotter] in package [laser_slam]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [laser_slam/scan_match_constraint_generator]: Cannot locate node of type [scan_match_constraint_generator] in package [laser_slam]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [laser_slam/scan_match_localizer]: Cannot locate node of type [scan_match_localizer] in package [laser_slam]

there was error, So I just started installing mongodb first.
If you know how to install mongodb, please teach me :)
Thank you

Jong

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33664/installing-mongodb-into-my-computer/) by [Jong H Kim](https://answers.ros.org/users/1617/jong-h-kim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2012-05-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can install warehousewg  [package](http://ros.org/wiki/warehousewg). This provides monodb and a ros wrapper over it.
Other errors refer to missing packages. You can search in ros repository for each of them. After install them, laser_slam should not pose much of a problem.

---

Originally posted by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) with karma: 660 on 2012-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bhaskara](https://answers.ros.org/users/95/bhaskara/) on 2012-05-10**:
Specifically, if on Ubuntu, do apt-get install ros-electric-warehousewg

**Comment by [bhaskara](https://answers.ros.org/users/95/bhaskara/) on 2012-05-10**:
Specifically, if on Ubuntu:

**Comment by [bhaskara](https://answers.ros.org/users/95/bhaskara/) on 2012-05-10**:
Specifically, if on Ubuntu:

**Comment by [Jong H Kim](https://answers.ros.org/users/1617/jong-h-kim/) on 2012-05-10**:
Thank you so much. I appreciate that.